# The inverse of the following 3x3 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I was asked to find the inverse of the following Matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1&-4&-6\\0&1&5\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

I took A|I where I is the 3x3 identity Matrix, row reduced it and got the following inverse Matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1&4&14\\0&1&-5\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

But apparently it's wrong. Any ideas on how to help?

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: Indeed that's not the inverse. Will you show us your computations?

Comment: I think that it should be $-14$ instead of $14$ please check your computations

Comment: Yes, it turned out to be -14 instead of 14. Slight error. Thanks.